# How can I set up a new keyword in LaTeX-mode

Tags: emacs

There is an expl3 library for LaTeX, that has functions like:

```
\fp_new:N
\fp_set:Nn
```

I am using LaTeX mode, and they are shown like this:

[image]

How can I make it show the whole function in a keyword color and ignore the underscore symbol in it?

I tried this:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'LaTeX-mode
  '(("\fp_new:N" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you using the built-in latex-mode?

Comment: I don't think LaTeX-mode is correct.  Try `latex-mode` instead.  If you are using a hook for something, then yes, it is `LaTeX`.

Comment: @lawlist It may sound strange, but there are 2 different modes in my Emacs: latex-mode and LaTeX mode. I am using LaTeX-mode.

Comment: @user4035 In vanilla Emacs, `LaTeX-mode` is just an alias for `latex-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

I have AUCTeX installed.  Here are some examples -- the second set of quotations would be empty instead of a wavy or square bracket.  I personally prefer to define my own font faces and my own keywords, which is a different format.

```
;; \EFFECT{[font-lock-function-name-face]}
(setq font-latex-match-function-keywords
    '(
        ("newcommandx" "*|{\\[[{")
    )
 )


;; \EFFECT{[font-lock-constant-face]}
(setq font-latex-match-reference-keywords
    '(
        ("fancypagestyle" "[{")
        ("fancyfoot" "[{")
    )
 )


;; \EFFECT{[font-lock-type-face]}
(setq font-latex-match-textual-keywords
    '(
        ("parentext" "{")
        ("hybridblockquote" "[{")
        ("parskip" "")
    )
)


;; \EFFECT{[font-lock-variable-name-face]}
(setq font-latex-match-variable-keywords
    '(
        ("newgeometry" "[{")
        ("quotingsetup" "[{")
    )
)


;; \font-latex-warning-face
(setq font-latex-match-warning-keywords
    '(
        ("fixme" "{") 
    )
)


;; only affects inside wavy brackets
(setq font-latex-user-keyword-classes
          '(("my-warning-commands"
                (("fixme" "{"))
                (:foreground "purple" :background "yellow")
                command)))
```

---

Here is another example that uses my own font faces:

```
(defvar lawlist-regular (make-face 'lawlist-regular))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-regular nil :background "white" :foreground "black" :font "Courier" :height 180)


(font-lock-add-keywords 'latex-mode '(

("INCLUDE\\|REVISED" 0 lawlist-red t)

("\\(foo\\)-\\(bar\\)" (1 lawlist-super-orange t) (2 lawlist-super-cyan t))

("\\(hello\\) \\(World\\)" (1 lawlist-super-orange t) (2 lawlist-super-blue t))

) 'prepend)
```